# JavaScript Button With Link

Tags: javascript, button, window.location

I am trying to set up a button that on click will redirect to a new link. I have tried so many different options and I just cannot get it to work.

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "$1.00";

divInnerElement.appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  window.location('http://www.google.com','_blank');
  return false;
});
```

Update: The function works but it only reloads the current page vs redirecting you to different page. If I use window.open it works but I dont want it to open a new window.

Update:

So I am not sure what was causing the click when using window.location but I was able to add an aTag into the button and that then resolved the problem.

```
<script>
var button = document.createElement("button");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.com');
aTag.innerHTML = '$1.00';
button.appendChild(aTag);
divInnerElement.appendChild(button);

// button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
//   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
// return false;
// });  
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried? Please include this info in your post.

Comment: Please add more details with what is not working? WHere are you trying to open? Is that a popup blocked window? Are you getting any errors in the console? Please provide more details.

Comment: I feel like I should add more context. The function works but it only reloads the current page vs redirecting you to different page. If I use window.open it works but I dont want it to open a new window.

Comment: `window.location` is not a function, you should be getting an error on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, Here is some working code- hope it's what you need

Html:

```
<div id="divInnerElement"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "$1.00";

document.getElementById('divInnerElement').appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
  return false;
});
```

I used window.open: since you put in your original snippet `_blank`, I'm assuming  you would like to open the link in a new tab.

Comment: She's added a comment saying that he doesn't want to open a new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should be in bottom of the page and remove the return statement from code so that page will be open in new tab.

```
 var button = document.createElement("button");
 button.innerHTML = "$1.00";

 document.getElementById('divInnerElement').appendChild(button);

 button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure what was causing the click when using window.location but I was able to add an aTag into the button and that then resolved the problem.

```
<script>
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.com');
    aTag.innerHTML = '$1.00';
    button.appendChild(aTag);
    divInnerElement.appendChild(button);

    // button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    //   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    // return false;
    // });  
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all this is against accessibility and kind of deceiving to the user based on the html elements being used on the page for their functionality. In your case if the user is being navigated to another page it should be created as an anchor element instead of button IMO. If you need the look of a button for it just use css to style it accordingly.

Comment: This isn't an answer. At best, this should be a comment (and you have plenty of rep to do so). Accessibility has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: Before down voting please check if there is anything misleading with the info added. I mentioned the very basic rule that if not followed breaks accessibility. There is no context added to the question why it has to be implemented that way. If in case there is no such requirement he can very well move to basic without having any complications is what I'm trying to say for anyone viewing this answer.

Answer (score -2):

In brief this could be because the script is executed before the page loads. Try and move the script to the bottom of the page.

Comment: If the script were executing before the page loads she wouldn't see the button that it adds.